# Sub views (layouts, templates) in Slim php framework

Tags: php, templates, frameworks, slim

I'm trying out the [Slim php framework](http://www.slimframework.com/)

Is it possible to have layouts or sub views in Slim? I'd like to use a view file as a template with variables as placeholders for other views loaded separately.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The slim framework makes use of other templating engines such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) so as long as you choose a templating engine that allows subviews, then it'll work. For more info on view templating in Slim, check [here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html).

Comment: The Slim documentation link is broken.

Answer (score 21):

filename: myview.php

```
<?php
class myview extends Slim_View
{
    static protected $_layout = NULL;
    public static function set_layout($layout=NULL)
    {
        self::$_layout = $layout;
    }
    public function render( $template ) {
        extract($this->data);
        $templatePath = $this->getTemplatesDirectory() . '/' . ltrim($template, '/');
        if ( !file_exists($templatePath) ) {
            throw new RuntimeException('View cannot render template `' . $templatePath . '`. Template does not exist.');
        }
        ob_start();
        require $templatePath;
        $html = ob_get_clean();
        return $this->_render_layout($html);
    }
    public function _render_layout($_html)
    {
        if(self::$_layout !== NULL)
        {
            $layout_path = $this->getTemplatesDirectory() . '/' . ltrim(self::$_layout, '/');
            if ( !file_exists($layout_path) ) {
                throw new RuntimeException('View cannot render layout `' . $layout_path . '`. Layout does not exist.');
            }
            ob_start();
            require $layout_path;
            $_html = ob_get_clean();
        }
        return $_html;
    }

}
?>
```

example index.php:

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
require 'myview.php';

// instantiate my custom view
$myview = new myview();

// seems you need to specify during construction
$app = new Slim(array('view' => $myview));

// specify the a default layout
myview::set_layout('default_layout.php');

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    // you can override the layout for a particular route
    // myview::set_layout('index_layout.php');
    $app->render('index.php',array());
});

$app->run();
?>
```

default_layout.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- $_html contains the output from the view -->
        <?= $_html ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm working with my View:

```
class View extends \Slim\View
{
    protected $layout;

    public function setLayout($layout)
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    public function render($template)
    {
        if ($this->layout){
            $content =  parent::render($template);
            $this->setData(array('content' => $content));
            return parent::render($this->layout);
        } else {
            return parent::render($template);
        }
    }
}
```

You may add some method like `setLayoutData(..)` or `appendLayoutData(..)`

---

Few minutes ago:

```
class View extends \Slim\View
{

    /** @var string */
    protected $layout;

    /** @var array */
    protected $layoutData = array();

    /**
     * @param string $layout Pathname of layout script
     */
    public function setLayout($layout)
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setLayoutData($data)
    {
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot append view data. Expected array argument.');
        }

        $this->layoutData = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function appendLayoutData($data)
    {
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot append view data. Expected array argument.');
        }

        $this->layoutData = array_merge($this->layoutData, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Render template
     *
     * @param  string $template Pathname of template file relative to templates directory
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($template)
    {
        if ($this->layout){
            $content = parent::render($template);

            $this->appendLayoutData(array('content' => $content));
            $this->data = $this->layoutData;

            $template = $this->layout;
            $this->layout = null; // allows correct partial render in view, like "<?php echo $this->render('path to parial view script'); ?>"

            return parent::render($template);;
        } else {
            return parent::render($template);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is great! How should I pass data to the main layout?

Comment: @GonzaloNaveira, you should use setLayoutData() or appendLayoutData() methods =). Sorry for not having answered your letter sooner =)

Answer (score 4):

With Slim 3

```
namespace Slim;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class View extends Views\PhpRenderer
{
    protected $layout;

    public function setLayout($layout)
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    public function render(ResponseInterface $response, $template, array $data = [])
    {
        if ($this->layout){
            $viewOutput = $this->fetch($template, $data);
            $layoutOutput = $this->fetch($this->layout, array('content' => $viewOutput));
            $response->getBody()->write($layoutOutput);
        } else {
            $output = parent::render($response, $template, $data);
            $response->getBody()->write($output);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

In layout:

```
<?=$data['content'];?>
```

Comment: No need for that when using the PhpRenderer with Slim 3. A "setLayout()" method already exists. https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#rendering-in-layouts

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your parent view:

```
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$app->render('subview.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the output in a variable, it's as easy as using the view's `fetch()` method:

```
//assuming $app is an instance of \Slim\Slim
$app->view()->fetch( 'my_template.php', array( 'key' => $value ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. If you do not want to use any template engine like smarty or twig. If you want to use only .php view file. Follow these steps.

Step 1. Make a new directory in your project's root directory. e.g templates.

Step 2. Open dependencies.php and paste below code

```
$container = $sh_app->getContainer();

$container['view'] = function ($c) {
   $view = new Slim\Views\PhpRenderer('src/templates/');
   return $view;
};
```

Step 3. In your controller's method for rendering view code should be looking like this.

```
$this->container->view->render($response,'students/index.php',['students' => $data]);
```