# SLIM custom skeleton

Tags: php, slim

I have downloaded SLIM and ran the hello world. But I wanted  to arrange the project as following :

```
app
|___config
|
|___controllers
|___models
|___views
|    |_____layouts
|          |___master.php
|          |___left.php
|___vendor
|___web
|   |___index.php
|   |___assests
```

Now I wanted something which could work as SERVICE BROKER and move the flow of application from Router to Controller. I wanted to use PHP as template not SMARTY or TWIG.

I am thinking to create a file inside APP folder which 'll collect the slug and accordingly transfer the control to a particular Controller.

Is there any other idea which 'll help me achieve described above.

Comment: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Skeleton

Comment: Please select one of these answers if they solved your problem.

Comment: Try This : https://packagist.org/packages/amitkhare/slim-hmvc-skeleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slim 2.4.0 now allows for [adding Controllers to routes](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/releases/tag/2.4.0). Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure did I understand what do you want but lets try.

For organizing routes and controllers check this out http://nesbot.com/2012/11/5/lazy-loading-slim-controllers-using-pimple.

You don't need to use pimple because Slim in his new version has DI (http://docs.slimframework.com/#DI-Overview).

And about template.. I don't like twig nor smarty so I'm using something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15856190/1293041.

Answer (score 0):

I find this tutorial sound good and very nearer to my solution. Here is the [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/taming-slim-20--net-30669).

Comment: If you can, please pick the relevant partes of the solution in the link and post them here, and if that solved your problem accept the answer.